# Keyboard character is undefined error

Tags: languages, input-encodings

I'm trying to compile a simple ISO-8859-2 document,

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage[latin2]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[paperwidth=18cm, paperheight=13cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
České vysoké učení technické v Praze
\end{document}
```

The compilation fails at the "č" letters. It keeps saying

```
! Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined
(inputenc) in inputencoding `latin2'.
```

despite the fact that "č" is a latin2 character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seems to be a conflict between the encoding used in your document and the one of your editor.  Both encodings: the one declared in your document using `inputenc` and the one used for your editor need to be the same; otherwise errors will appear. Make sure both coincide and the problem will disappear.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the use of latin2 is mandatory in my project.

Comment: @Grant may I ask why is this so?

Comment: I'll be processing csv files that are in ISO-8859-2.

Comment: @Grant I see. Is your editor configured to also use ISO-8859-2?

Comment: I set it to ISO-8859-2, rewrote the sample and it started working. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
```

at the beginning of your document. It works for me.

Comment: Hello and welcome to TeX.SE! I'm afraid that the fact it works for you does not mean it answers the posted question. I'm actually 100% sure it does not, since the code in the question requires latin1 encoding, and you'd be supplying utf8 to it.

Comment: In LaTeX document? Till to now I was convinced that ones need to write `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` ...