# Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined

Tags: symbols, input-encodings

I am using Lyx. I want my text to appear as Strategist's instead of Strategistâs. Please help.

These I include in the LAtex Preamble under documents settings

```
\input{LyXPreamble}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}  
\usepackage{selinput}
```

The following from JabRef:

```
@Misc{Schrauf2016a,
      author   = {Schrauf, Reinhard Geissbauer, Jesper Vedsø and Stefan},
      title    = {A Strategist’s Guide to Industry 4.0},
      month    = {May 9,},
      year     = {2016},
      abstract = {Global businesses are about to integrate their operations into a seamless digital whole, and thereby change the world.},
      number   = {Mar 20,},
      url      = {http://www.strategy-business.com/article/A-Strategists-Guide-to-Industry-4.0?gko=7c4cf},
      volume   = {2017},
    }
```

I got the following errors:

[image]

[image]

The remaining package inputence error are the exact same thing. Please help.

Comment: So do write  Strategist's instead of Strategistâs. Without MWE we cannot probably say much more.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Please show us a [minimal but working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates what you have done. Without such an example questions are often somehow unclear and could be closed without an answer. Nevertheless, undefined keyboard characters are often the result of using an option for `inputenc` that does not correspond with the encoding used in the editor.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71517/do-i-need-fontenc-and-inputenc, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115853/keyboard-character-is-undefined-error, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19427/how-do-i-change-the-encoding-of-my-files

Comment: You will want to check the encoding of your file (did you save it as UTF-8 or with some ISO... encoding?), compare it with what LaTeX expects in `inputenc`, and you will want to have a look at `fontenc`.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke I improved my question.

Comment: @moewe I used these but still no avail: http://imgur.com/uMuaKcp

Comment: Use `'` instead of the smart quote `’` or load `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and encode your document in UTF-8.

Comment: @moewe It works! Thank you so much. I use the dumb quote. How do I promote your comment as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `'` instead of `’`

```
Strategist's
```

While `’` worked for me with everything set up for UTF-8, in older versions you might run into trouble with it.